# React-Window in React inside Map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-virtualized, react-window

I implemented `react-window` and `react-virtualized-auto-sizer`.

My problem is that it crashes. It says `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

```
import AutoSizer from 'react-virtualized-auto-sizer'
import { FixedSizeList as List } from 'react-window'

...
{
  !isRetrievingProducts &&
    products?.length > 0 &&
    products?.map((product, productIndex) => (
      <AutoSizer>
        {({ height, width }) => (
          <List
            className="List"
            height={height}
            itemCount={5}
            itemSize={35}
            width={width}
          >
            <Grid
              key={product?.productCode || productIndex}
              component="div"
              container
            >
              <Grid
                component="div"
                item
                xl={10}
                lg={12}
                md={12}
                sm={12}
                xs={12}
              >
                <ProductCard productIndex={productIndex} product={product} />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </List>
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    ));
}
```